# Parsing and searching a text file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, parsing

**What I have:** A list of counties, states, & codes in a file.txt with a "," as the delimiter:

```
001001,Autauga, AL
001003,Baldwin, AL
001005,Barbour, AL
001007,Bibb, AL
001009,Blount, AL
001011,Bullock, AL
001013,Butler, AL
```

**What I want to do:**

Search for a specific code given I have the county and state.

**Thoughts:**
Load in the entire file with ajax and parse it:

```
$.ajax({
    url : CountyAndStateURL,
    type : 'GET',
    dataType : 'txt',
    crossDomain : true,
    success: function(data) {
    pageExecute.fileContents = data;
```

Thats where I am lost...How can I search through this text file and find the code given I know the county and state?

Comment: you can use a RegExp to find the line without splitting, or split the text into lines, maybe into columns to, and filter lines until you have the ones you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a loop.

```
var result = [];
var rows = text.split('\n');
for (var r = 0; r < rows.length; r++) {
    var items = rows[r].split(',');
    var item = {};
    item.code = items[0];
    item.name = items[1];

    result.push(item);
}

console.log(result);
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g2nxv3q8/)**

To get the code just test like this:

```
if (item.state == state && item.county == county)
    return item.code;
```

Comment: add a simple if statement and compare each one with my county and state...I guess?

Comment: This will give unexpected results when handling a txt file saved on a Windows app (it breaks the Windows' new-line character `\r\n`).

Comment: @JoshCox Yes, you can do that.

Comment: @Teemu you can write `text.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n").split('\n');`

Comment: ... or just `rows = text.split(/\r\n|\n/)`.

Comment: Ah, that does look better indeed, I'm not that great with regex.

Comment: Jonathan, can you throw the if statement into the solution.

Answer (score 2):

If your list is long and you'll be doing many lookups, you can use a dictionary to make this more time-efficient: In dictionary, every lookup has a time complexity O(log(n)), which is a bit better than O(n) solutions.

My proposed solution:

```
var text =
    "001001,Autauga, AL\n" +
    "001003,Baldwin, AL\n" +
    "001005,Barbour, AL\n" +
    "001007,Bibb, AL\n"    +
    "001009,Blount, AL\n"  +
    "001011,Bullock, AL\n" +
    "001013,Butler, AL\n";

// Split the text in lines
// (Trim it first to get rid of any newline character at the end)
var lines = text.trim().split("\n");

// Regular expression for line's content
var regex = /\s*(.+)\s*,\s*(.+)\s*,\s*(.+)\s*/;

var dict = { };

lines.forEach(function(lineStr) {
    var matchResult = lineStr.match(regex);
    var key = {
        county: matchResult[2],
        state : matchResult[3]
    };
    var code = matchResult[1];

    dict[key] = code;
});

// Lookup in dict:
console.log(dict[{ county: "Bibb", state: "AL" }]);
```

**EDIT: How does my regex work?**

```
var regex = /\s*(.+)\s*,\s*(.+)\s*,\s*(.+)\s*/;
```

`\s` - any whitespace character

`\s*` - 0 or more whitespace characters

`.` - any character except new line

`.+` - one or more characters (except new lines)

`( )` - capture group: the content that matches the rules inside the bracket will be written to array that is a result of String.match() function.

`,` - just a comma character

Comment: Thanks. :) Though a correct answer given faster is certainly the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert CSV (comma-separated-values) to JSON with this function from 
[HERE](http://techslides.com/convert-csv-to-json-in-javascript)

```
//var csv is the CSV file with headers
function csvJSON(csv){

  var lines=csv.split("\n");     
  var result = [];     
  var headers=lines[0].split(",");

  for(var i=1;i<lines.length;i++){     
      var obj = {};
      var currentline=lines[i].split(",");

      for(var j=0;j<headers.length;j++){
          obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
      }

      result.push(obj);     
  }

  //return result; //JavaScript object
  return JSON.stringify(result); //JSON
}
```

THEN, find it with something like:

```
// the code you're looking for
var needleCode = 001005;
var needleCounty = 'Barbour';

// iterate over each element in the array
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length i++){
  // look for the entry with a matching `code` value
  if (obj[i][0] === needleCode && obj[i][1] === needleCounty){
     // we found it
    // obj[i][1] is the matched county
    // obj[i][2] is the matched county code 
  }
}
```

Comment: I follow you, but I have the county and state. Can I use these both as needles simultaneously or do it twice?